# Disable aspect ratio or image crop on wordpress custom header images

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone help me with either disabling the aspect ratio for custom header image cropping in the wordpress 2011 theme, or disabling the cropping altogether?

At this stage I just need to get it done, even if it means modifying the core files. I've googled solutions, but have found none so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well what you want to do, I think you can look at the functions.php file of the theme.

You will see these lines :

```
// The height and width of your custom header.
// Add a filter to twentyeleven_header_image_width and twentyeleven_header_image_height to change these values.
define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', apply_filters( 'twentyeleven_header_image_width', 1000 ) );
define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', apply_filters( 'twentyeleven_header_image_height', 288 ) );

// We'll be using post thumbnails for custom header images on posts and pages.
// We want them to be the size of the header image that we just defined
// Larger images will be auto-cropped to fit, smaller ones will be ignored. See header.php.
set_post_thumbnail_size( HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT, true );

// Add Twenty Eleven's custom image sizes
add_image_size( 'large-feature', HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT, true ); // Used for large feature (header) images
add_image_size( 'small-feature', 500, 300 ); // Used for featured posts if a large-feature doesn't exist
```

If you want to change the behaviour of the crop, you just have to set the third parameter of the *add_image_size()* function to **false** as you can see it in the [add_image_size() codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

I hope that's what you want, if not, let me know ;)

Comment: If this answer helped, don't hesitate to mark the question as resolved ;)